# How to find list of directories names with locations under given path with exact pattern matching with recursive

Tags: html, linux, shell

Below is my command

`find <path>  -type d  -name "FY09"`

I need to have recursive search under path

Comment: can you please explain more?

Comment: I am trying to get directories which starts with FY09. While using above command it is not recursive one. Need to have recursive path searching.

Comment: This question has many answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153144/how-can-i-recursively-search-for-directory-names-with-a-particular-string-where)

Answer (score 0):

[find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) is recursive but if you are searching for directories that start with a string you should use wild card character `*`

```
find <path> -type d -name "FY09*"
```

Comment: How to delete that output of above command. I have used -delete. But no improve.

Comment: @lakshmisowmya This should do `find <path> -type d -name "FY09*" | rm -rf`